# Can I discard more than 1 card at a time if there are no draw cards left?

Tags: saboteur-2

Ordinarily no one would discard more than one card when there are no draw cards available. In this situation though, the player discarded down to one card on one turn, and then on the next turn played his remaining card, a Swap Hands card, on a player he suspected was on the opposite team, thus preventing the other player from playing.

It was a brilliant move, and I don't see anything in the rules specifically preventing this.

Is this legal?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Did both of these actions (discard to the last, play the  swap) occur in the same turn or did they occur on consecutive turns?

Comment: I read it as two separate turns for my answer.

Comment: Question clarified. Clearly taking two actions in one turn is illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at rules [here](https://tesera.ru/images/items/98031/Saboteur_expansion_rules.pdf) I think your interpretation is correct.  Although I suspect from the way you say "its a brilliant move, and I don't see anything specifically preventing this" makes me think whoever you did this against didn't agree!

anyway the rules quotes....

On a players turn one of there options is

> Pass and discard 1-3 face-down cards from your hand..... then draw 1-3 cards.

The note underneath clarifies

> When the pile is used up, no cards are drawn.

So if there were a situation where a player is to draw a card and can't they simply don't get a card.  So yes you can discard cards knowing you can't draw back and deliberately shrinking your hand size.

The rules for swapping state :-

> The player who plays this card chooses one other player and exchanges hands with them. Discard the action card, then the other player gets to draw 1 card!

So you swap your remaining hand of zero cards with the other player.  They are unable to draw a card as non left.

So yes the move seems entirely legal based on that.

Comment: For the record it wasn't me who did it or who was on the receiving end; I was the one who called shenanigans who couldn't back up my claim.

Comment: I stand corrected!